# Rails shopify/stripe/braintree/twilio webhooks testing on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, stripe-payments, shopify, braintree

I'm trying to configure shopify/stripe/braintree/twilio webhooks for localhost. It's showing destination not verified. Please suggest some methods which are compatible with ruby-rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ngrok** configurations are changed in version 2

ngrok is easy to install. Download a single binary with zero run-time dependencies for any major platform. Unzip it and then run it from the command line.

```
$ unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip
```

now run it like below

```
$ ./ngrok http 3000
```

Answer (score 4):

To run webhooks on localhost you need to create public tunnel on you local development environment. There are different providers such as UltraHook and ngrok. They are easy to setup such as:

For UltraHook

```
$ gem install ultrahook
$ ultrahook stripe 3000
Authenticated as senvee
Forwarding activated...
http://stripe.senvee.ultrahook.com -> http://localhost:3000
```

For Ngrok you need to download on your machine from https://ngrok.com/download then run this command on your machine.

unzip it `$ unzip /path/to/ngrok.zip`

and run it by:

```
./ngrok http 3000
```

3000 is your localhost port number. It will give you an URL, you need to setup webhook with this url.

Answer (score 2):

Nitesh's answer is on point. We love [ngrok at Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) and use it all the time to [start sending messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/ruby/install) from server-side code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'


# Get your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = 'ACCOUNT_SID'
auth_token = 'AUTH_TOKEN'
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

message = @client.account.messages.create(:body => "ngrok is awesome!",
        :to => "+1415XXXXXXX",     # Replace with your phone number
        :from => "+1415XXXXXXX")   # Replace with your Twilio number
puts message.sid
```